# deleting multiple files (versions) with Fog and Carrierwave - Rackspace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, rackspace-cloud, fog, rackspace

I am building an application where i have a file with original, medium and thumbnail size images. I am using carrierwave to accomplish this, and I need to remove all versions of the file from Rackspace Cloud Files:

```
class StyleImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  version :medium do
      process :resize_to_limit => [460, 460]
  end

  version :thumb do
      process :resize_to_limit => [100, 100]
  end

  def filename
      "#{Digest::MD5.hexdigest(original_filename . Time.now.to_s)}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename
  end
end
```

However, when i do a destroy through console, it is only removing the original version... How do i go about deleting all the versions? I also get this error in console, but it still does remove the single file

```
#<Fog::Storage::Rackspace::NotFound: Fog::Storage::Rackspace::NotFound>
```

Controller destroy method:

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    @image = Image.find(params[:id])
    @image.destroy
    render :json => true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the filename method... its naming the files differently, 1 second off as the Time.now is recalled. It looks as though the filename method runs on each version method, which the timestamp is off.

Solution:
https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Use-a-timestamp-in-file-names